# cors c# web API react

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

(My English is not good)
Hello so I am having problem where when I have my web API on my server and then try to use my react website from my main pc I get Cors error. when I run both my webAPI and my react on my main pc it owrks but need it to work from the server coz we are several ppl wokring on it.

I would love it someone could help me out.

Error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ServerIP/api/user. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

I have tried some different things like adding:

```cs
public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()));
```

and then when that didn't work I tried fixing the end point

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Also tried adding this infront of our two controller classes

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
```

This is how the React looks like:

```js
import Axios from 'axios'

const WorkifyAPI = Axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://ServerIP:42069/api'
})

export default WorkifyAPI
```

the react service:

```js
import http from '../WorkifyAPI'
const GetallWorkouts = (userID: string) => {
    return http.get(`/user/${userID}/WorkoutData`)
}

export default {
    GetallWorkouts,
}
```

EDIT:
How the starup.cs Currently looks like

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();

            services.AddControllers();

        }

        public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

When I did run my React in Chrome instead I got this Error instead:
*net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID*
So it is something with the SSL as @sideshowbarker said so will look over that

This is the request from Devtool (?)
[image: picture of teh request from devtool]

Comment: Which dotnet version are you using ?

Comment: As far as I can see, the code is correct. I had a similar issue were it turned out that the reverse proxy was stripping the CORS headers. 
Maybe this is the same in your situation?

Comment: I have just tested with my .net core 2.1 and the code in the answer below is working fine.

Comment: “CORS request did not succeed” actually indicates the problem is something other than CORS-related. I literally means the browser failed to successfully complete the request. Or in other words, it means the transaction never reached the point of the server actually responding. It most often indicates an SSL failure. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed.

Comment: I think sideshowbarker and Mekroebo are probably correct and the issue isn't related to frontend app or backend app configuration. you should show the actual requests in web developer tools.

Comment: @TamTam I am using 3.1

Comment: calling `https` at port `42069` for `https://ServerIP:42069` could very well be an indication of a proxy.  in which case, configuring ssl proxy (and/or handling client settings in that regard) is probably the path forward on this

Answer (score 0):

Declare `AddCors()` in `ConfigureServices` function and `UseCors()` in `Configure` function worked for me.
It should be like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddCors();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
    app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
}
```

The `Configure` function is changed depends on the version but this should work.

Comment: @Tehpson can you a provide your full code for setting up cors ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with do something like this:

```
 services.AddCors(action =>
                action.AddPolicy("AllowOrigins", builder =>
                    builder
                        //.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                        .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                )
            );
```

tjhen in your:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors("AllowOrigins");

}
```